# UWP - ImageBrush full path to ImageSource

Tags: win-universal-app

I have an ellipse and I want to fill it with image. And I would like to set full path to the image to `ImageSource` property of `ImageBrush`. But I wasn't able to accomplish it.

I've tried to add:

- *C:/Users/someuser/Pictures/untitled.png*
- *C:\\Users\\someuser\\Pictures\\untitled.png* which came from `FilePicker`
- *C:\Users\misko\Pictures\untitled.png*.

But non of this works. Can you please explain to  me how to properly set full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the file first using `FilePicker`

```
if (file != null)
{
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

    var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

    var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

    grid.Background = new ImageBrush
    {

        ImageSource = bitmapImage
    };
}
```

Comment: So I can only bind bitmaps to the ImageSource of ImageBrush?

Comment: Yes, there is no way to use the full path to a file outside of the application sandbox to bind to ImageSource

Comment: Besides the default locations, an UWP app may access files in certain special folders, provided that the file access is declared in the app's capabilities. See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) for details.

Comment: True, you can access the file. That's why I can read it to create the bitmap image.

Comment: So If I want to remember what image user picked I cannot simply remember  the path to the image but I have to copy and store it in app local folder?

Comment: You use `FutureAccessList` https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457